# Adding a WCF Service reference in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

Following an example about WCF, it seems that in VS 2010 you could right click the references, hit "Add Service Reference", and then hit the "Discover" to get find services in the solution.

This does not work in VS 2013. I have my Service dll, I have a service host, but it will not find any services.
Clean, rebuild, try again -> same outcome.

I'm running VS as an administrator (Win 8 + VS 2013 -> can't run WCF if not admin).

The option of running the service through VS and then adding a reference does not exist (won't allow to add service reference when running), so the only solutions I've found are:

- Use svcutil manually (works though)
- run the service.exe manually (as admin), and then point to it's end point.

Any ideas what's up?